# Why is there a connection to browserstack.com via curl on log in (OS X)?

Tags: browserstack

Using Little Snitch to monitor network connections I see:

> On 30 Oct 2018, curl tried to establish a connection to www.browserstack.com. The request was denied automatically during login.

Anybody know what that could be to do with, or what the purpose of it is?  I  searched but did not find.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some insight into what is the issue you are facing with regards to 'www.browserstack.com' and 'OS X'? Elaborate on which logs you are referring to?

Comment: I'm not experincing any issues. I would like to know what the purpose of the connection, and I'm interested in why my laptop is connecting to a server during log in (which seems unusual in itself).

Comment: Do you have an account with BrowserStack? Is there any BrowserStack desktop app running in the background? You may try to track down the process that is triggering this call!!

Comment: I do have an account with browser stack, no I do not believe the app should be running on log in, especially since it is not enabled as a login item in OSX.